# How can I use this library to draw the map in my C file?

Tags: c, pointers

I have .a and .h file which contains a map I need to draw(just some lines), and there's three functions in that header file:

1- `unsigned char get_line_count(void);`
which returns the number of lines in this library

2- `unsigned int* malloc_lines(unsigned int size);`
which inputs size of memory I need to allocate for the map and returns pointer to the allocated block of memory

3- `void copy_lines(unsigned int* lines);` 
which inputs pointer to a block of memory got from previous method
This function copies the library's data for the map from program memory (PROGMEM), into the memory pointed to by the input argument.

The lines I get from the library are in following format:

```
int lines[] = {
    line_0_x0, line_0_y0, line_0_x1, line_0_y1,
    line_1_x0, line_1_y0, line_1_x1, line_1_y1,
    ...
    line_n_x0, line_n_y0, line_n_x1, line_n_y1,};
```

And I have a draw_line method in my c file: `draw_line(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2,);`
`x1,y1` is the start point and `x2,y2` is the end point

I'm confusing about how to use these functions to draw the lines.
All files linked correctly.
Thank you for any advice

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format the code.

Comment: As a note: Although they share similarities, C and C++ are different languages with differing "natural" solutions to problems. You should generally only tag the language you are writing/compiling.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure getting you:

```
Line 0 = draw_line( lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3]);
Line 1 = draw_line( lines[4], lines[5], lines[6], lines[7]);
...
Line N = draw_line( lines[N*4], lines[(N*4)+1], lines[(N*4)+2], lines[(N*4)+3]);
```

then if I understand well

```
int i=0;
int N = get_line_count();
unsigned int *lines = malloc_lines(N);
copy_lines(lines);

for (i=0; i<N; i+=4)
{
   draw_line( lines[i], lines[i+1], lines[i+2], lines[i+3]);
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to post a better description of library functions to help people understand how it works.

Comment: @zhanmu: If you get another *picture* then you must not be using the correct data set. So does it come close to what you require? does it draw another map? does it draw Mickey Mouse instead?